# unobfuscate Assembly-CSharp.dll?

Tags: obfuscation

First: sorry about English, it's not my language. The translation was done by Google Translate.
I'm trying to work on a .dll from a Unity game, I managed to decompile the entire game, open the .dll, but it is obfuscated and I can't unobfuscate it in any way. Do you know of any way I can deobfuscate the .dll? I can't go to the next step.

Answer (score 1):

If Microsoft Intermediate Language (MSIL) was converted to C++ code using IL2CPP you can use this excellent tool to retrieve symbols of functions : https://github.com/Perfare/Il2CppDumper